# Manipulating values not matching HH:MM:SS format - python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```py
    arrival     departure
0   23:55:00    23:57:00
1   23:57:00    23:59:00
2   23:59:00    24:01:00
3   24:01:00    24:03:00
4   24:03:00    24:05:00
```

I am working with data that cover a whole day and part of the day after. Data are (most of the time) in the `HH:MM:SS` format. However some time values are higher than 23:59:59 and go up to 27:00:00.

I would like to get the time difference between `departure` and `arrival` columns.

I tried using `datetime` to do that but I guess something went wrong:

```py
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'

delta = datetime.strptime(df['departure'], FMT) - datetime.strptime(df['arrival'], FMT)
```

Which raises the following error:

```py
ValueError: time data '24:01:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

Is there a way to get the time difference between these two columns even though their format do not always match the `HH:MM:SS` format?

Comment: Do you have the dates available as well?

Comment: No I don't, I only have the time values.

Comment: Use `timedelta`, not `datetime`? `df.apply(pd.to_timedelta)`. Then you can subtract and get 2 minutes for every row.

Comment: Not quite what OP need apparently @alollz, see [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60229683/9698684)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use timedelta from [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

```
import datetime

delta1 = datetime.timedelta(hours=23, minutes=59, seconds=0)
delta2 = datetime.timedelta(hours=24, minutes=01, seconds=0)
timedelta = delta2 - delta1
>>> timedelta # or timedelta.to_seconds()
datetime.timedelta(seconds=120)
```

Give you the delta in seconds. Full example:

```
import datetime

arrival = "24:01:00"
departure = "24:03:00"


def get_time_from_string(t):
    return dict(
        zip(["hours", "minutes", "seconds"], list(map(lambda x: int(x), t.split(":"))),)
    )


delta1 = datetime.timedelta(**get_time_from_string(arrival))
delta2 = datetime.timedelta(**get_time_from_string(departure))

delta = delta2 - delta1
print(delta.total_seconds())
```

Comment: So, from what I understand I need to specify the hours/minutes/secondes values for each rows, right ?

Comment: I have assumed he can extract the given hours, minutes and seconds from a string to a dict that satisfies the timedelta.

Otherwise: `dict(zip(["hours", "minutes", "seconds"], list(map(lambda x: int(x),"23:55:00".split(":")))))` sth like this might do it

Comment: Using ```timedelta``` was very helpful thank you very much! I didn't use the same method as your example but it still worked really well.